# CakePHP HABTM Find all rows with or without associated records

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to select all records **with or without** a related HABTM relationship in CakePHP 2.x

I can run this query to select the source and related records, but is it possible to also get records which don't have an associated record in the same query?  I've found queries to do this separately but not in a single query.

I would expect that Servicetemplatedoc would be null or empty if there was no associated record as the Servicetemplate model is where I want all records from.

```
$query = [
    'recursive' => -1,
    'fields' => [
        'Servicetemplate.*'
        'Servicetemplatedoc.*',
    ],
    'joins' => [
        [
            'table' => 'servicetemplatedocs_to_servicetemplates',
            'alias' => 'ServicetemplatedocsToServicetempaltes',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => [
                'ServicetemplatedocsToServicetempaltes.servicetemplatedoc_id = Servicetemplatedoc.id',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'table' => 'servicetemplates',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'alias' => 'Servicetemplate',
            'conditions' => 'Servicetemplate.id = ServicetemplatedocsToServicetempaltes.servicetemplate_id'
        ],
    ]
];

$result =  $this->find('all', $query);
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = [
'recursive' => -1,
'fields' => [
    'Servicetemplate.*'
    'Servicetemplatedoc.*',
],
'joins' => [        
    [
        'table' => 'servicetemplates',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'alias' => 'Servicetemplate',
        'conditions' => 'Servicetemplate.id = ServicetemplatedocsToServicetempaltes.servicetemplate_id'
    ],
    [
        'table' => 'servicetemplatedocs_to_servicetemplates',
        'alias' => 'ServicetemplatedocsToServicetempaltes',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => [
            'ServicetemplatedocsToServicetempaltes.servicetemplatedoc_id = Servicetemplatedoc.id',
        ],
    ],
];


$result =  $this->find('all', $query);
```

First Servicetemplates then Servicetemplatesdocs 
Reverse the tables

Comment: Thank-you for replying, however I'm now finding I get a MySQL error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ServicetemplatedocsToServicetempaltes.servicetemplate_id' in 'on clause'
Any ideas?

Comment: Add 'foreignKey' => false ,

Comment: That seems to make no difference, it's strange changing to order back it works but only returns items with a link